# How can I refactor this JavaScript code to avoid making functions in a loop?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, closures, event-delegation

I wrote the following code for a project that I'm working on:

```
var clicky_tracking = [
  ['related-searches', 'Related Searches'],
  ['related-stories', 'Related Stories'],
  ['more-videos', 'More Videos'],
  ['web-headlines', 'Publication']
];

for (var x = 0, length_x = clicky_tracking.length; x < length_x; x++) {
  links = document.getElementById(clicky_tracking[x][0])
                  .getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var y = 0, length_y = links.length; y < length_y; y++) {
    links[y].onclick = (function(name, url) {
      return function() {
        clicky.log(url, name, 'outbound');
      };
    }(clicky_tracking[x][1], links[y].href));
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- define a two-dimensional array, with each instance the inner arrays containing two elements: an `id` attribute value (e.g., "related-searches") and a corresponding description (e.g., "Related Searches");
- for each of the inner arrays, find the element in the `document` with the corresponding `id` attribute, and then gather a collection of all `<a>` elements (hyperlinks) within it;
- loop through that collection and attach an `onclick` handler to each hyperlink, which should call `clicky.log`, passing in as parameters the description that corresponds to the `id` (e.g., "Related Searches" for the `id` "related-searches") and the value of the `href` attribute for the `<a>` element that was clicked.

Hopefully that wasn't thoroughly confusing! The code may be more self-explanatory than that.

I believe that what I've implemented here is a closure, but JSLint complains:

http://img.skitch.com/20100526-k1trfr6tpj64iamm8r4jf5rbru.png

So, my questions are:

- How can I refactor this code to make JSLint agreeable? Or, better yet, is there a best-practices way to do this that I'm missing, regardless of what JSLint thinks?
- Should I rely on event delegation instead? That is, attaching `onclick` event handlers to the `document` elements with the `id` attributes in my arrays, and then looking at `event.target`? I've done that once before and understand the theory, but I'm very hazy on the details, and would appreciate some guidance on what that would look like - assuming this is a viable approach.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegation is a better approach. JSLint complains because you are creating a new function each time within the loop. However, instead of setting up a single event on the document to listen for all click events, I would rather setup a handler on all individual root elements that have id's assigned to them. A single handler can be reused for all these elements.

```
function logClick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var link = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if(link.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "a") {
        return;
    }

    var name = clicky_tracking[this.id];
    clicky.log(link.href, name, 'outbound');
}
```

Register the above handler with each root element.

```
for(var id in clicky_tracking) {
    var root = document.getElementById(id);
    root.onclick = logClick;
}
```

Also to avoid searching through the array, I've changed `clicky_tracking` from array to an object for easier keyed access.

```
var clicky_tracking = {
  'related-searches': 'Related Searches',
  'related-stories': 'Related Stories',
  'more-videos': 'More Videos',
  'web-headlines': 'Publication'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This code isnt very maintainable! I hate shoving jQuery down your throat but this looks like a situation where is would be very useful to you, something like:

```
$('a.trackable').click(function(e) {

  clicky.log(url, name, 'outbound');
};
```

You could enable tracking by adding class 'trackable' to each link, and map links to a lookup table by using eg $(this).attr('rel').

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, James! That does make sense, and I appreciate the answer and your approach. Unfortunately I absolutely can't use jQuery on this project - it's deployed in a very high-traffic environment and even the 24KB weight of jQuery is too much.

Comment: Even using jquery from eg the google CDN? So you'd actually cut down your outgoing traffic because of less js ... ? Just a thought :D

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function to build the event handlers, e.g.:

```
function createClickHandler(url, name) {
  return function () {
    clicky.log(url, name, 'outbound');
  };
}

for (var x = 0, length_x = clicky_tracking.length; x < length_x; x++) {
  links = document.getElementById(clicky_tracking[x][0]) // NOTE:links should be 
                  .getElementsByTagName('a');            // declared at the top
  for (var y = 0, length_y = links.length; y < length_y; y++) {
    links[y].onclick = createClickHandler(clicky_tracking[x][1], links[y].href);
  }
}
```

I also think that [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) is also a really good option, you can implement it very easily:

```
var clicky_tracking = [
  ['related-searches', 'Related Searches']
  //...
], elem;

function createClickHandler(name) { // capture only the 'name' variable
  return function (e) {
    e = e || window.event; // cross-browser way to get the event object
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement; // and the event target

    if (target.nodeName == "A") { // make sure that the target is an anchor
      clicky.log(target.href, name, 'outbound');
    }
  };
}

for (var x = 0, len = clicky_tracking.length; x < len; x++) {
  elem = document.getElementById(clicky_tracking[x][0]); // find parent element
  elem.onclick = createClickHandler(clicky_tracking[x][1]); // bind the event
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks very much, CMS! I wish I could accept both your answer and Anurag's, but they were both great and his was the first by just a few minutes. FWIW, this was very helpful to me.